# Python IndexError Opening .nc file

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I cannot figure out how to resolve this error I'm seeing when I try to open this .nc file which looks like this:

```
remote_var
Out[99]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 721, lon: 1440, time: 1)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 90.0 89.75 89.5 89.25 ... -89.25 -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * lon      (lon) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0 ... 359.0 359.2 359.5 359.8
Dimensions without coordinates: time
Data variables:
    M        (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 721, 1440), meta=np.ndarray>
```

My error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\U321103\.spyder-py3\ERA5_MAPPING\ERA5_MAP_100M_WSPD.py", line 35, in <module>
selectvar.M.plot()
IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

My code looks like this:

```
#The easiest way to read the data is:
path = "//porfiler03/gtdshare/VORTEX/ANOMALY_FILES/anomaly.M.2021.05.vs30y/era5.M.2021.05.nc"
remote_var = xr.open_mfdataset(path,combine='nested',concat_dim='time')

selectvar = remote_var.where((-135 < remote_var.lon) & (remote_var.lon < -60)
         & (25 < remote_var.lat) & (remote_var.lat < 50), drop=True)
#plot M
plt.figure()
selectvar.M.plot()

exit()
```

thank you for any help here!

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly open the `Dataset` in `remote_var`.  If you want a subset of `remote_var`, you may try `.sel()` as:

```py
selectvar = remote_var.sel({'lon':slice(-135, -60), 'lat':slice(25, 50)})
```

If there are multiple grids for different variables, you can use:

```py
selectM = remote_var.M.sel({'lon':slice(-135, -60), 'lat':slice(25, 50)})

selectM.plot()
```